# ngSanitize was removed with bower now I get a ngSanitize Missing Exception

Tags: angularjs, sanitize

When I installed angularjs with yeoman I got asked to install some additional packages like:

- angular-route
- angular-sanitize

etc...

Now I remove angular-sanitize with:

```
bower uninstall --save angular-sanitize
```

When I start my index.hmtl page with

```
grunt server
```

Then my browser window is white/empty and the browser console says:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module appApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngSanitize due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngSanitize' is not available! You either misspelled the mo...<omitted>...1)
```

1) Now I ask myself WHY can I optionally install an angular plugin which is needed by the core angular.js.

2) How can I fix the mess ? I do not need ngSanitize.

Comment: It's not needed by angular core. It's needed by a module of your application. Remove the dependency to this module in your source code.

Comment: You were right I removed the dep. but now I have to fix the new ui-router stuff because I removed the ngRoute :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write angular apps you have the ability to include modules.

```
angular.module('myApp', [ 'ui.router', 'ngAnimate','ngSanitize']);
```

when you do not have a dependency loaded..  ie: you uninstall it, you ALSO have to remove it from your application modules or it will throw the error that you have listed.  You must remove the 'ngSanitize' as well as the .js file for it to be unloaded.

```
angular.module('myApp', [ 'ui.router', 'ngAnimate']);
```

see how now ngSanitize is no longer listed.  do a find in your project and locate it and remove it from the modules list.

Comment: That worked but I still had to remove the angular-route module which is a bit more work ;-)